# is there a way to make a prompt in JS return a number?

Tags: javascript, prompt

I am trying to make a program which involves the user entering how long they want the timer to run but it seems that prompt can only return a string, is there a way I can get it to return a number?

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can convert the string to a number

```
var res = prompt('How long');
var length = parseInt(res, 10);
if (isNaN(length)){
  //enter a number
}
```

Comment: You have a typo: `isNAN` --- should be `isNaN`

Answer (score 1):

You can use prompt to get the input as String and then parseInt() to convert it to an integer.

```
var sAge = prompt("Enter your age");
var age = parseInt(sAge,0);
```

[Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/rhnz4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

No, you must convert the string to a number then, using parseInt()

e.g. `var integer = this_is_a_string_variable.parseInt();`

You should check if the input was valid before you do parseInt(). Do it by walking through the letters.

```
for(var i=0; i<string.length; ++i)
    if(!(string[i]>='0' && string[i]<='9'))
        //Error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Number()** function also

```
 var price = prompt("Enter total price");
 var price = Number(price);
```